# jquery animate with step function not running as it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make a canvas animation using jquery animate and step callback function.
The problem I'm facing is that the animation is running too fast. If I set the duration to 6 seconds, it runs in less than 1 second, and then I have to wait another 5 seconds for the complete callback.

Here is a video recording. I've traced the "now" param in the step function and the time passed since start:
http://screencast.com/t/pPj87yBVOKY

You can see that the browser is trancing values while the animation is running, then it stops for a few seconds and then it goes to the end.

Here is some code :

```
obj.percent = 0;
        $(obj).animate({percent: 100},{duration: transitionConfig.tweenDuration * 1000, easing: getEasing(transitionConfig.tweenType, transitionConfig.easeType), complete: onTransitionEnd, step: processFrame});

function processFrame(x, y) {
        timePassed = new Date().getTime() - time;

        showOutput.width = showOutput.width;
        showOutput.height = showOutput.height;
        var cx = config.width / 2;
        var cy = config.height / 2;
        var rad = Math.sqrt(cx * cx + cy * cy);
        var start = 0;

        var amount = x;
        console.log(x, timePassed);
        showDraw.beginPath();
        showDraw.moveTo(cx, cy);
        showDraw.lineTo(config.width, cy);
        showDraw.arc(cx, cy, rad, start, amount, false);
        showDraw.lineTo(cx, cy);
        showDraw.closePath();
        showDraw.fillStyle = pattern;
        showDraw.fill();
    }
```

Comment: Do you seriously expect us to be able to help without seeing one single line of code?

Comment: I've updated the text with some code